# Hide button function if statement issue - Swift

Tags: swift, function, iboutlet

I have a function to hide a slider if another button is pressed. I currently have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sliderHide: UISlider!

@IBAction func sliderHide(sender: UISlider) {
    if (buttonPlay.selected) {
        sliderHide.hidden = false
    }
    else if (!buttonPlay.selected) {
        sliderHide.hidden = true
    }
}
```

The build is running but the slider only hides if itself is selected. It does nothing if the button is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Use == not = when comparing,= is an assignment operator.

Moreover, if buttonImage is not a variable representing the control state of a button, but the button itself you want to do:

```
if buttonImage.selected == false {

}
```

However, you should use an @IBAction for the button if you want to run a function when it is pressed.

Please consider using an @IBAction for this kind of thing unless your button is programmatically created. You can read more about it here:

http://rshankar.com/different-ways-to-connect-ibaction-to-uibutton/

I

Comment: more than that... he's comparing the button to a button state

Comment: @Sethmr I assumed buttonImage was a poorly named variable for a control state.

Comment: I can't think of a time when you would have a variable for that outside of as a parameter. Since it wasn't a parameter, I assumed not. I guess when it comes to other's code, assuming is bad haha

Answer (score 0):

[image]I think you want

add an Outlet to the slider like the picture and then wherever you play the sound, make the sliderYouMightHide.hidden = false and wherever the sound stops make the sliderYouMightHide.hidden = true. You might also want to make it hidden in viewDidLoad

Comment: Also, I really don't like the name of the button. A button has an image, so I would consider renaming the button something else =P

Comment: I changed the button names for the purposes of the question don't worry - I obviously chose bad examples :)

Comment: The function does not work - I created it within IBAction connecting to the slider - was this correct?

Comment: hmmmm avoid using the term button when refering to a slider haha

Comment: [documentation for UISlider](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISlider/continuous)

Comment: you can only use one of the designated action types. Why would you want to hide a slider whenever it is not being used anyhow? How are people soposed to click something they can't see until they click it?

Comment: So there are multiple icons which each have sounds - the user only needs to change the volume of sounds that are active - when the sounds are not active the slider may be hidden

Comment: I have updated the question! - there is one more issue